# Allow RESTful DELETE method in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, rest

im currently setting up asp.net to accept DELETE http verb in the application. 
However, when i send

```
"DELETE /posts/delete/1"
```

i always get a 405 Method not allow error. I tried to take a look at the header:

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   private
Pragma  No-Cache
Allow   GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5, Private-Server
Date    Tue, 17 Nov 2009 18:30:31 GMT
Content-Length  5590
```

**Allow GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE**

notice the Allow header in IIS7, it's only allow GET HEAD OPTIONS and TRACE. I currently using [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)] in my delete controller (i think this one is extended by MVCContrib, correct me if im wrong)

PS: i send DELETE using Javascript:

```
  function _ajax_request(url, data, callback, type, method) {
      if (jQuery.isFunction(data)) {
          callback = data;
          data = {};
      }
      return jQuery.ajax({
          type: method,
          url: url,
          data: data,
          success: callback,
          dataType: type
      });
  }
```

and:

```
 _ajax_request($(this).attr('href'), "", function(d) { alert("submit"); }, "json", 'DELETE');
```

THank you in advance!

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644/any-way-to-handle-put-and-delete-verbs-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC 2 has this built in. You don't need MVCContrib for it. See [HtmlHelper.HttpMethodOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.httpmethodoverride%28VS.100%29.aspx) and [HttpDelete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpdeleteattribute%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: should i go for asp.net mvc 2 since it's still in beta stage? :)

Comment: Up to you. We have (not production yet, but soon). Works fine.